# I need help resolving dual display issues with 13.04 running the ATI Radeon Open Source driver

Tags: unity, ati, compiz, 13.04

I did a fresh install of 13.04 on my Dell Precision M6500. I was previously running 12.04 LTS. My laptop has an ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5870 adapter and I'm using the open source driver.

Plugging in an external display on boot enables mirroring which is nice by default. Since I want to run this off to extend my display, I use the display adapter utility to uncheck mirror and apply. about 50% of the time, I get a crash of Unity and/or Compiz.

I lose the launcher and the title bars on my window and the ability to change windows. Pretty scary stuff since 12.04 LTD didn't have this problem. To recover my apps, I do a Ctrl-Alt-F1 to get to a terminal, log in, cross my fingers, and run:

```
unity --replace
or
DISPLAY=:0 unity --replace
```

I then do a Ctrl-Alt-F7 and pray that my apps respond again so that I can close them and restart. If I don't get my apps to respond, I'll try this from a console terminal:

```
DISPLAY=:0 compiz --replace
```

This will sometimes get my apps back, albeit without Unity. At least I can close them gently. If I can't get my apps back, I have to close the apps I can and restart via Ctrl-Alt-Del and home that my hidden applications panic.

I will also get Unity / Compiz crashes when using Shutter and sometimes when accessing the Stormcloud weather application.

I tried the proprietary ATI drivers, and they were worse, with Mirroring on by default and attempting to unmirror via the ATI utility or the Ubuntu display manager not working either. I was also getting the virtual display adapter resolution error and I wasn't ready to have manually maintained a xorg.conf file.

Here are some display particulars for my system:

```
jim@jim-Precision-M6500:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Broadway XT [Mobility Radeon HD 5870] [1002:68a0]
Subsystem: Dell FirePro M7820 [1028:12ef]
Kernel driver in use: radeon
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Juniper HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5700 Series] [1002:aa58]
jim@jim-Precision-M6500:~$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on AMD JUNIPER
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 9.1.1

Not software rendered: yes
Not blacklisted: yes
GLX fbconfig: yes
GLX texture from pixmap: yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program: yes
GL fragment program: yes
GL vertex buffer object: yes
GL framebuffer object: yes
GL version is 1.4+: yes


Unity 3D supported: yes
```

So I'm quite frustrated at this point and the 3 to 5 Unity crashes a day are unproductive.

Any advice out there?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have what I believe might be a related issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is for Ubuntu 10.10 but this might help.
http://milindshakya.tumblr.com/post/4952304640/setting-up-external-monitor-as-the-primary-monitor-in

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks Thunder, but I want my laptop display to be my primary.  I just can't have Unity & Compiz crash using dual displays.  When using my primary, this crash never happens.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem with my computer setup. I installed 13.04 onto my desktop where I am using two monitors and similar to your situation when I tried to deselect the mirror display option my computer would lose the launcher and the title bars on windows and the ability to change windows.

Here was my fix. (sorry i do not have images, I do not know how yet)
1. Go to software updater and click on "settings" then select the "additional drivers" tab. Make sure the correct driver in selected...On my computer it is "X.org X server..." driver.

1. Go to "Ubuntu Software Center" type "xorg" in the search bar and install the "NVidia binary X.Org driver"
2. Go back to display and deselect the mirror option and it should work.

Additionally when I was using 12.04 I followed step 1 above but for step 2 would have to install the "ATI binary X.Org driver" found by typing "ATI" into the softwear center and then step 3. would to search  applications by typing "amd" and tweaking the amd catalyst settings.

I hope that this helps, it worked for me.